# Noise Issue After Applying FastICA to Audio Data in Python

Tags: python, audio

I am working on a Python script that separates audio sources from a podcast file using Fast Independent Component Analysis (FastICA) from scikit-learn. After applying FastICA and exporting the separated audio, I am experiencing noise in the output.

I tried this (update from 21/10/2023)

```
# Importing required libraries and packages for audio processing and visualization
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import spectrogram
from scipy.fft import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to generate a spectrogram for an audio segment
def generate_spectrogram(audio_segment):
    samples = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
    samples = samples.astype('float64')
    samples /= samples.std(axis=0)
    f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(samples, audio_segment.frame_rate)
    return f, t, Sxx

# Function to generate a spectral response histogram for an audio segment
def generate_spectral_histogram(audio_segment):
    samples = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
    samples = samples.astype('float64')
    samples /= samples.std(axis=0)
    yf = fft(samples)
    plt.hist(np.abs(yf), bins='auto')
    plt.title("Spectral Response Histogram")
    plt.xlabel("Frequency")
    plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    plt.show()

# Function to generate a RMS histogram for an audio segment
def generate_rms_histogram(audio_segment):
    samples = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
    rms_values = np.sqrt(np.mean(samples**2))
    plt.hist(rms_values, bins='auto')
    plt.title("RMS Histogram")
    plt.xlabel("RMS Value")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.show()

# Function to generate a sample value histogram for an audio segment
def generate_sample_value_histogram(audio_segment):
    samples = np.array(audio_segment.get_array_of_samples())
    plt.hist(samples, bins='auto')
    plt.title("Sample Value Histogram")
    plt.xlabel("Sample Value")
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.show()

# Load noisy audio (for demonstration, using a short segment)
# NOTE: Replace this with the actual noisy audio file path
# noisy_audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("1247910-m-6a6af34210e31ae783db5916a9e09518.mp3")[:5000]

# Load normal audio (for demonstration, using a short segment)
# NOTE: Replace this with the actual normal audio file path
# normal_audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("separated_voice_1.wav")[:5000]

# Since I can't access external files, I'll generate synthetic noisy and normal audio for demonstration
fs = 44100  # Sample rate
T = 1.0    # Seconds
t = np.linspace(0, T, int(T*fs), endpoint=False) # Time array
# Generate a 440 Hz sinusoidal signal as "normal" audio
normal_audio_signal = 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440 * t)
# Generate "noisy" audio by adding noise to the "normal" audio
noisy_audio_signal = normal_audio_signal + 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=len(t))

# Create AudioSegment objects from the numpy arrays
normal_audio = AudioSegment(
    normal_audio_signal.tobytes(),
    frame_rate=fs,
    sample_width=2,
    channels=1
)
noisy_audio = AudioSegment(
    noisy_audio_signal.tobytes(),
    frame_rate=fs,
    sample_width=2,
    channels=1
)

# Generate and visualize spectrogram for noisy audio
f, t, Sxx = generate_spectrogram(noisy_audio)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10 * np.log10(Sxx))
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.title('Spectrogram of Noisy Audio')
plt.colorbar(label='Intensity [dB]')
plt.show()

# Generate and visualize spectrogram for normal audio
f, t, Sxx = generate_spectrogram(normal_audio)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10 * np.log10(Sxx))
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.title('Spectrogram of Normal Audio')
plt.colorbar(label='Intensity [dB]')
plt.show()

# Generate and visualize spectral histogram for noisy audio
generate_spectral_histogram(noisy_audio)

# Generate and visualize spectral histogram for normal audio
generate_spectral_histogram(normal_audio)

# Generate and visualize RMS histogram for noisy audio
generate_rms_histogram(noisy_audio)

# Generate and visualize RMS histogram for normal audio
generate_rms_histogram(normal_audio)

# Generate and visualize sample value histogram for noisy audio
generate_sample_value_histogram(noisy_audio)

# Generate and visualize sample value histogram for normal audio
generate_sample_value_histogram(normal_audio)
```

[image: Noisy audio]
[image: Original]
[image: Noisy]
[image: Original]

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import FastICA

# Load and preprocess the audio
audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3('podcast_file.mp3')
samples = np.array(audio.get_array_of_samples())
samples = samples.reshape(-1, audio.channels)

# Standardize the data
standardized_samples = samples.astype('float64')
standardized_samples /= standardized_samples.std(axis=0)

# Apply FastICA
ica = FastICA(n_components=audio.channels, tol=0.1, max_iter=500)
S = ica.fit_transform(standardized_samples)

# Export the separated audio
# ... (Code for exporting audio)
```

What I've Tried:

Standardizing the audio data before applying FastICA.
Adjusting FastICA parameters such as tol and max_iter.
Despite these adjustments, the noise issue persists.

Questions:

- What could be causing this noise issue in the separated audio?
- Are there any advanced noise reduction techniques that could be applied to improve the audio quality?

Comment: Is the noise being introduced, or is it present in the original data? Can you provide more details about the noise, such as its pattern or frequency? It would be helpful if you could show a spectrogram, a spectral response histogram, and an RMS or sample value histogram for the noisy audio compared to the normal audio. Have you tried using a different audio file to see if the issue persists? Additionally, are you aware that FastICA assumes the sources to be statistically independent and non-Gaussian? How confident are you that this approach is suitable for separating voices in a podcast?

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you for the hints. I've updated the post

Comment: I can also provide the original mp3

Comment: The spectrogram of the normal audio looks like it's just garbled noise. Is the MP3 file being decoded correctly? Seems like not.